# Angular2: config file with APP_INITIALIZER - css conflict?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've created with angular-cli an Angular 2 App and it's working quite well.

Since I've the need to set some parameters in a config file in assets folder (in order to make it available in dist folder), I've searched in the forum and followed the steps that suggest to load an external file with APP_INITIALIZER (like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651991/how-to-update-json-file-without-rebuilding-in-angular-cli))

Now, the problem is that when I add in **app.module.ts** the ConfigService in the providers element like this:

```
  providers: [
      ConfigService,
      {
        provide   : APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: ConfigLoader,
        deps      : [ConfigService],
        multi     : true
      },

      TestJsonService,
      { provide: HighchartsStatic,
        useFactory: highchartsFactory}

    ],
```

something goes wrong with the plugin I've used for the file selection ([kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput))

This is the screenshot of the app 
without the declaration of the ConfigService in the providers
[image]

This is what happens declaring the ConfigService in the providers
[image]

It seems like there's something that conflicts in css.

I really can't understand what is the problem and if there is a reason why the ConfigService and the fileinput plugin conflicts.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
Below some relevant files that could be helpful to understand the problem:

This is the **config.json** placed in *assets* folder

```
{
  "URL_1": "http://url1",
  "URL_2": "http://url2",
}
```

Then I add the reference to this file in the **environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  configFile: 'assets/config.json'
};
```

Then in **config.ts** I have the class that match the elements of the JSON:

```
export class Configuration {
  URL_1: string;
  URL_2: string;;
}
```

and the corresponding service in **config.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Configuration } from './config';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private config: Configuration;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  load(url: string) {
    console.log("load config");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(config => {
          this.config = config;
          resolve();
        });
    });
  }

  getConfiguration(): Configuration {
    return this.config;
  }

}
```

This is the entire **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestJsonComponent } from './test-json/test-json.component';
import { TestJsonService } from "./test-json.service";
import { UploadFileComponent } from './upload-file/upload-file.component';
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import { WordCloud } from './prova-word-cloud';
import { SortPipe } from './sort-by.pipe';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ConfigService } from './config.service'; 
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'; 

declare var require: any;
export function highchartsFactory() {
  var hc = require('highcharts');
  var hcm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  var sg = require('highcharts/modules/wordcloud');
  hcm(hc);
  sg(hc);
  return hc;
}

 export function ConfigLoader(configService: ConfigService) {  
  return () => configService.load(environment.configFile); 
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestJsonComponent,
    UploadFileComponent,
    WordCloud,
    SortPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DataTableModule,
    ChartModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide   : APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: ConfigLoader,
      deps      : [ConfigService],
      multi     : true
    },

    TestJsonService,
    { provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory}

  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally, this is the **angular-cli.json** created by angular-cli and modified adding the css and scripts needed:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "anon-cli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.scss",
        "./assets/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css",
        "./assets/bootstrap-fileinput/themes/explorer/theme.css",
        "./assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
        "./assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [                                              
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ,
        "./assets/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js",
        "./assets/bootstrap-fileinput/js/it.js",
        "./assets/bootstrap-fileinput/themes/explorer/theme.js",
        "./assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js",
        "./assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table-it-IT.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be much clearer if you show the code, and not the screenshots of the rendered app. For one, the code for the plugin you wrote. For two, the specific CSS classes/rules that are clashing.

Comment: Hi! Could you tell me please which are the relevant files (or part of them) that I should post that can be useful to understand the problem?

Comment: Well, as I've said, ConfigService and plugin you wrote. You said those two are in conflict, if you can extract the relevant parts there, it would help.

Comment: Ok, I've added some pieces of code. If I have to post something else please let me know. Thanks